jQuery Hide or show an element upon confirming delete
I have the following PHP loop:
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($order->products); $i++) {
    
    $id = $order->products[$i]['id']; 
...
...               
    echo '

<div id="piGal_' . $id . '">
    <ul id="piList_' . $id . '">
    </ul>
    <div id="receive_inventory_button_' . $id . '"><button id='RECEIVE INVENTORY' ...></div>
    </div>
    <div id="add_new_location_' . $id . '">
        <a href="#" onclick="addNewPiForm_' . $id . '();return false;">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="float: left;"></span>ADD NEW</a></div>
 
    <div id="piDelConfirm_' . $id . '" title="Delete This Location?">
        <p><span>...</span>Please confirm the removal of this location.</p>
    </div>';
...
...

}
                  

And I have the following  jQuery code to delete an item with confirm delete button.
  
var piDelConfirmId_' . $orders_products_id . ' = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {$("#piDelConfirm_' . $id . '").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "DELETE": function() {
      $("#piId" + piDelConfirmId_' . $id . ').effect("blind").remove();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "CANCEL": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
});
function showPiDelConfirm(piId) {
  piDelConfirmId_' . $id . ' = piId;

  $(\'#piDelConfirm_' . $id . '\').dialog(\'open\');
}
</script>

This works fine.
Now I want to hide one element and show another element instead, when delete is confirmed. So I add the  below 2 lines
$("#receive_inventory_button_' . $id . '").css({"visibility": "hidden", "display": "none"});
$("#add_new_location_' . $id . '").css({"visibility": "visible", "display": "block"});

within the
"DELETE": function() {
      ....
}

This somehow doesn't work:
  buttons: {
    "DELETE": function() {
      $("#piId" + piDelConfirmId_' . $id . ').effect("blind").remove();
      $(this).dialog("close");

      $("#receive_inventory_button_' . $id . '").css({"visibility": "hidden", "display": "none"});
      $("#add_new_location_' . $id . '").css({"visibility": "visible", "display": "block"});

    },

I would much appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance.
Upon clicking on the CONFIRM delete button the dialog box window closes. However,  the following 2 lines don't get executed
$("#receive_inventory_button_' . $id . '").css({"visibility": "hidden", "display": "none"});
$("#add_new_location_' . $id . '").css({"visibility": "visible", "display": "block"});

Here is the actual HTML:
<style type="text/css">
#piList_1745 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#piList_1745 li { margin: 5px 0; padding: 2px; }
</style>

var piSize_1745 = 3;

function addNewPiForm_1745() {
  $('#piList_1745').append('<li id="piId' + piSize_1745 + '" style="padding:14px; border: 1px solid #c5dbec;"><a href="#" onclick="showPiDelConfirm(' + piSize_1745 + ');return false;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float: right;"></a><table><tr><td>Model:</td><td>10X20-T</td></tr><tr><td>Units:</td><td><input type="number" name="number_of_units" id="number_of_units" /></td></tr></table></li>');
  piSize_1745++;
}
  
var piDelConfirmId_1745 = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {$("#piDelConfirm_1745").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "DELETE": function() {
      $("#piId" + piDelConfirmId_1745).effect("blind").remove();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "CANCEL": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
});
function showPiDelConfirm(piId) {
  piDelConfirmId_1745 = piId;
  $('#piDelConfirm_1745').dialog('open');
}
</script>


<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="piGal_1745">
            <ul id="piList_1745"> </ul>
            <div id="receive_inventory_button_1745" style="padding-left: 250px; padding-bottom: 50px; text-align:left; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#1a539a;"><span class="tdbLink">
                 <button id="tdb6" type="submit">RECEIVE INVENTORY</button></span><script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb6").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-disk"}}).addClass("ui-priority-primary").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");</script></div>
        </div><div id="add_new_location_1745" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
            <a href="#" onclick="addNewPiForm_1745();return false;" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#1a539a;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="float: left;"></span>Receive Returns</a></div>
        
        <div id="piDelConfirm_1745" title="Delete This Location?">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Please confirm the removal of this location.</p></div>
    </td>
</tr>
   
   
   

<style type="text/css">
#piList_1746 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#piList_1746 li { margin: 5px 0; padding: 2px; }
</style>

var piSize_1746 = 2;

function addNewPiForm_1746() {
  $('#piList_1746').append('<li id="piId' + piSize_1746 + '" style="padding:14px; border: 1px solid #c5dbec;"><a href="#" onclick="showPiDelConfirm(' + piSize_1746 + ');return false;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float: right;"></a><table><tr><td>Model:</td><td>10X20-T</td></tr><tr><td>Units:</td><td><input type="number" name="number_of_units" id="number_of_units" /></td></tr></table></li>');
  piSize_1746++;
}
  
var piDelConfirmId_1746 = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {$("#piDelConfirm_1746").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "DELETE": function() {
      $("#piId" + piDelConfirmId_1746).effect("blind").remove();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "CANCEL": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
});
function showPiDelConfirm(piId) {
  piDelConfirmId_1746 = piId;
  $('#piDelConfirm_1746').dialog('open');
}
</script>


                          
<tr>
    <td>                  
        <div id="piGal_1746">
            <ul id="piList_1746"> </ul>
            <div id="receive_inventory_button_1746" style="padding-left: 250px; padding-bottom: 50px; text-align:left; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#1a539a;"><span class="tdbLink"><button id="tdb7" type="submit">RECEIVE INVENTORY</button></span><script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb7").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-disk"}}).addClass("ui-priority-primary").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");</script></div>
        </div>
                  
        <div id="add_new_location_1746" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
             <a href="#" onclick="addNewPiForm_1746();return false;" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#1a539a;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="float: left;"></span>Receive Returns</a></div>
 
        <div id="piDelConfirm_1746" title="Delete This Location?">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Please confirm the removal of this location.</p></div>
     </td>
</tr>







<style type="text/css">
#piList_1747 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#piList_1747 li { margin: 5px 0; padding: 2px; }
</style>

var piSize_1747 = 3;

function addNewPiForm_1747() {
  $('#piList_1747').append('<li id="piId' + piSize_1747 + '" style="padding:14px; border: 1px solid #c5dbec;"><a href="#" onclick="showPiDelConfirm(' + piSize_1747 + ');return false;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float: right;"></a><table><tr><td>Model:</td><td>10X20-T</td></tr><tr><td>Units:</td><td><input type="number" name="number_of_units" id="number_of_units" /></td></tr></table></li>');
  piSize_1747++;
}
  
var piDelConfirmId_1747 = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {$("#piDelConfirm_1747").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "DELETE": function() {
      $("#piId" + piDelConfirmId_1747).effect("blind").remove();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "CANCEL": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
});
function showPiDelConfirm(piId) {
  piDelConfirmId_1747 = piId;
  $('#piDelConfirm_1747').dialog('open');
}
</script>


So, the way it works is, on page load the div containing the "RECEIVE INVENTORY" button (i.e. receive_inventory_button_1745, receive_inventory_button_1746, etc.) is hidden and the div containing the "Receive Returns" link (i.e. add_new_location_1745, add_new_location_1746, etc.) is visible.
When clicked on "Receive Returns", the "Receive Returns" becomes hidden, while some input fields along with the "RECEIVE INVENTORY" button becomes visible. So the user can enter the date and hit on "RECEIVE INVENTORY" button to add the data into the database. However if the user changes his/her mind and clicks on "CLOSE DIALOG" icon, it closes the dialog pop-up window. What I want to add is simultaneously close the div containing the "RECEIVE INVENTORY" button (i.e. receive_inventory_button_1745, receive_inventory_button_1746, etc.); and show the div containing the "Receive Returns" link (i.e. add_new_location_1745, add_new_location_1746, etc.).
Here is the "CLOSE DIALOG" icon format above:
<a href="#" onclick="showPiDelConfirm(' + piSize_1745 + ');return false;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float: right;"></a>

I hope I was able to explain my agenda. I have removed unnecessary stylings and HTML lines to make it easier to understand.
Thanks in advance.

You're missing the $ before id here: $("#add_new_location_' . id . '")

Instead of creating an event binding for each ID, with all the $id substitution, you should give them a class and bind the event handler to the whole class. Then you can use $(this) in the handler to refer to the current element, and use navigation methods to find related elements.


Edit your question and add the browser-rendered HTML, not the PHP-coded HTML. will help us to understand your HTML structure. 2) when removing the location becomes successful you want to hide/remove the whole corresponding div(<div id="piGal_' . $id . '">) or just the button?


@Death-is-the-real-truth  thanks for the recommendations. I  added the HTML and explained a bit more.

@Barmar thanks for the comments. The $ sign, I removed accidentally, as to creating a class, it's a developed site and the whole site has the same template. I just need to make this small hide/visible option work on this page. :)

You should be able to put a breakpoint in the code, then single-step it from there to see what's happening.
